# SQL Distinct Columns and Nulls

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join

I'm trying to left outer join on 3 fields in 3 SQL tables. The goal is, given a query for object (O1) in table T1 with 3 elements (E1, E2, E3) in table T2 and 2 secondary features (S1, S2) in table T3, return a result set that looks like:

```
 O1 | E1 | S1
 O1 | E2 | S2
 O1 | E3 |
```

How would I go about doing this for multiple objects? I've tried left outer joins, group by, and a combination of different SQL queries but can't seem to return the rows in a way that isn't too many combinations.S

Here is the simplest example I have tried which returns 6 results:

`select a.O, b.E, c.S from 
    T1 a 
    left outer join T2 b on a.O = b.O 
    left outer join T3 c on a.O = c.O
    where a.O in ('O1');`

Results returned would be:

`O1 | E1 | S1
 O1 | E1 | S2
 O1 | E2 | S1
 O1 | E2 | S2
 O1 | E3 | S1
 O1 | E3 | S2`

Note: left outer join is used because I need the table to return results even if T2 or T3 do not have results.

Comment: Please show the queries you have attempts.  Also, any clarification you man make to the description would be helpful.

Comment: Can you post a more detailed information about your db structure?  Include the bigger sample data and desire output. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/)

Comment: I guess `L1, L2` on your sample should be `S1, S2` on your description

Comment: Apologies. Updated with a simple query I've tried. I can update with more if you like but do not have them saved so I would have to go back and recreate them.

Comment: Your query looks right. Just add order by condition.

Comment: I tried  `order by a.O, b.E` and it just changed the order, not the number of columns returned

Comment: @mnv -- he wants the results show first with 3 rows.  He is getting the results shown second with 6 rows.  That does not look right.  That is his question

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want to do is treat T2 and T3 like they have a ordering and then join the orders together.  You can do that like this:

```
select a.O, b.E, c.S
from T1 a 
left outer join (
  SELECT T2.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER () as rn
  FROM T2     
) b on a.O = b.O 
left outer join (
  SELECT T3.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER () as rn
  FROM T3 
) c on a.O = c.O and b.rn = c.rn
where a.O in ('O1');
```

This won't work if T3 has more "elements" than T2.

If you want to do this for multiple objects in a then just add the following

```
select a.O, b.E, c.S
from T1 a 
left outer join (
  SELECT T2.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY O) as rn
  FROM T2     
) b on a.O = b.O 
left outer join (
  SELECT T3.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY O) as rn
  FROM T3 
) c on a.O = c.O and b.rn = c.rn
where a.O in ('O1');
```